I can't access an array that was dynamically allocated inside the function
I want to allocate memory for a two-dimensional array of char in a separate function. I defined a double pointer in the main function, then I passed this pointer into my separate function alloc_arr(), where the memory was allocated using malloc(). The problem is that after exiting the function alloc_arr(), I cannot access my array because I get a "segmentation fault" runtime error
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int alloc_arr(char **res)
{
    size_t i;

    res = (char **)malloc(200 * sizeof(char *));
    if (res == NULL)
        return 0;
    i = 0;
    while (i < 200)
    {
        res[i] = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
        if (res[i] == NULL)
            return 0;
        i++;
    }
    strncpy(&res[0][0], "string", 100);
    printf("res[0] = %s\n", res[0]);
    return 1;
}
void free_arr(char **res)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 200; i++)
        free(res[i]);
    free(res);
}
int main(void)
{
    char **res;
    res = NULL;
    if (alloc_arr(res))
        printf("res[0] = %s\n", res[0]); /* here I get the error */
    else
        return 1;
    free(res);
    return 0;
}

In the function alloc_arr(), I return a numeric value to indicate the possible error. I assume I can use the 'res' pointer after the end of the function because it was defined in the main. The malloc() should return the address of dynamic memory that I can use. At the same time, if I just return the pointer 'res' from the function alloc_arr(), this example works well.
I want to dynamically allocate memory for a two-dimensional array of char type (an array of strings), put one string into this array and print the value of the first element of the array. I have calculated to split my code into several parts by moving the code responsible for dynamic memory allocation into a separate function. However after performing the above operation I cannot access the first array element because I get a "segmentation fault" error. When I try to do the same with two-dimensional int array I get the same problem. Yes, I can do this:
int **alloc_int(int **res)
{
    size_t i;

    res = (int **)malloc(20 * sizeof(int *));
    if (res == NULL)
        return NULL;
    i = 0;
    while (i < 20)
    {
        res[i] = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
        if (res[i] == NULL)
            return NULL;
        i++;
    }
    res[0][0] = 10;
    printf("res[0] = %d\n", res[0][0]);
    return res;
}
void free_int(int **res)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 20; i++)
        free(res[i]);
    free(res);
}
int main(void)
{
    int **res;
    res = NULL;
    if ((res = alloc_int(res)) != NULL)
        printf("res[0] = %d\n", res[0][0]);
    else
        return 1;
    free(res);
    return 0;
}

And it works. Although I just want to know the reason why the first variant doesn't work. And how to force it to work.`

The problem with the first function is that the pointer defined in main is passed to the function by value. So the function deals with a copy of the pointer and changes the copy instead of the original pointer. The original pointer stays unchanged.

By the way the value of the parameter in the second function is not used. So the function should be declared like  int **alloc_int( void );

Side note: Using the function strncpy is a dangerous habit, as that function is not guaranteed to always write a terminating null character. If there is not enough room for the null character, the null character will be truncated before the actual string gets truncated, which is usually dangerous. I suggest that you use snprintf with the %s specifier instead, as that function will always write a terminating null character (unless the size of the memory buffer is zero).

Sorry your question got closed.  Here is your solution:  https://godbolt.org/z/d778fadjW
